# How to use setHTTPBody from UITextField input

Tags: ios, xcode, ios7, ios8, ios6

I am using mycontacts restful API to integrate in to my application. Now, I want to use username and password entered by UITextField not manually. I do not know, how to do it in setHTTPBody. Any suggestions?

```
NSURL *URL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"https://api.addressbook.io/v1/login"];

NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:URL];
[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];

[request setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];

//Here I want to use username and password obtained by UITextField.
[request setHTTPBody:[@"{\n  \"username\": \"Enter username\",\n  \"password\": \"EnterPassword\",\n  \"client\": \"apiary\"\n}" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

NSURLSession *session = [NSURLSession sharedSession];
NSURLSessionDataTask *task = [session dataTaskWithRequest:request
                                        completionHandler:
                              ^(NSData *data, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error) {

                                  if (error) {
                                      // Handle error...
                                      return;
                                  }

                                  if ([response isKindOfClass:[NSHTTPURLResponse class]]) {
                                      NSLog(@"Response HTTP Status code: %ld\n", (long)[(NSHTTPURLResponse *)response statusCode]);
                                      NSLog(@"Response HTTP Headers:\n%@\n", [(NSHTTPURLResponse *)response allHeaderFields]);
                                  }

                                  NSString* body = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
                                  NSLog(@"Response Body:\n%@\n", body);
                              }];
[task resume];
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess you do not want to have a button click on which webservice should be called. What you can do is set delegate for both UItextField and use this delegate method

```
- (void)textFieldDidEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField;
```

What this delegate method does is this will be called each time you move out of the textfield. here you can check whether user have entered both the textfield and set your http body.

Comment: [request setHTTPBody:[@"{\n  \"username\": \"Enter username\",\n  \"password\": \"EnterPassword\",\n  \"client\": \"apiary\"\n}" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]]; I have implemented those delegates and everything. I only want to know, how can I use those in above line, because above line is string body.

Answer (score 0):

Using NSString and format it with username and passsword from text field and sending that body to setHTTPbody.

```
NSURL *URL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"https://api.addressbook.io/v1/login"];

NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:URL];
[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];

[request setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];

//Improved code lines
NSString *username = ((UITextField*)[self.view viewWithTag:1]).text;
NSString *password = ((UITextField*)[self.view viewWithTag:2]).text;

NSString *body = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"{\n  \"username\": \"%@\",\n  \"password\": \"%@\",\n  \"client\": \"apiary\"\n}",username,password];

[request setHTTPBody:[body dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
 //Improved code lines end

NSURLSession *session = [NSURLSession sharedSession];
NSURLSessionDataTask *task = [session dataTaskWithRequest:request
                                        completionHandler:
                              ^(NSData *data, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error) {

                                  if (error) {

                                      [self alert:@"Error" message:@"Check network connection"];

                                      return;
                                  }

                                  if ([response isKindOfClass:[NSHTTPURLResponse class]]) {
                                      NSLog(@"Response HTTP Status code: %ld\n", (long)[(NSHTTPURLResponse *)response statusCode]);

                                      }
                                      NSLog(@"Response HTTP Headers:\n%@\n", [(NSHTTPURLResponse *)response allHeaderFields]);
                                  }

                                  NSString* body = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
                                  NSLog(@"Response Body:\n%@\n", body);
                              }];
[self.view endEditing:YES];
[task resume];
```